# texthero scatterplot using pca and kmenas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do clustering for words and I already calculated pca and k mean using texthero.

This is my dataframe.

[image: dataframe for pca and kmeans]

I want to use scatterplot for this but I get nothing, just blank. Am i missing something?
[image: scatterplot]

Answer (score 1):

[texthero](https://texthero.org/docs/api/texthero.visualization.scatterplot) uses plotly to render the plot, so chances are your renderer is set up properly inside the notebook you are using. You can try to update your plotly installation and also check the help page for plotly (https://plotly.com/python/renderers/) on how to display the plot.

You can see your choices of rendering with:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers
```

If I use an example dataset, it works:

```
import texthero as hero
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://github.com/jbesomi/texthero/raw/master/dataset/bbcsport.csv"
)
df['text'] = hero.clean(df['text'])
df['tfidf'] = (
    hero.tfidf(df['text'], max_features=100)
)
df['pca'] = hero.pca(df['tfidf'])
df['kmeans'] = hero.kmeans(df['tfidf'])
df['label'] = pd.Categorical(df['kmeans'],
                  categories=df['kmeans'].sort_values().unique())
```

You can plot with:

```
hero.scatterplot(df,col='pca',color = 'label',return_figure=True)
```

[image]

I am using jupyter notebook so you can also do:

```
fig = hero.scatterplot(df,col='pca',color = 'label',return_figure=True)
fig.show(renderer="notebook")
```